# How to access the structure of a Resource (down the visual tree) from code?

Tags: wpf, xaml, code-behind, resourcedictionary

I have a ControlTemplate defined in a ResourceDictionary:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="FacePositionSource">    
    <Grid>
        <Image x:Name="imagem" Width="1028" Height="524" Source="/Miotec.AtlasControl;component/Image/face.png"/>
        <Canvas>
            <local:MusclePositionControl x:Name="frontal" Angle="22" Canvas.Left="571.5" Canvas.Top="108"/>
        </Canvas>
        <Line x:Name="line" X1="0" X2="0" Y1="0" Y2="{Binding Height, ElementName=imagem}"  Margin="514,0,0,0"/>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

In code behind, I have:

```
    void AtlasFace_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var r = Application.Current.FindResource("FacePositionSource") as ControlTemplate;
        Console.WriteLine(r);
        // how to get those properties from "r"?
    }
```

When I put a breakpoint at "r", it actually refers to the control, but looks like I cannot "read from its entrails"? Should I make the elements public? Should I use some special method?

---

Some context:

This was created so that I could visually position some reference points of a CustomControl, using this ControlTemplate to read the positions programmatically.

Specifically, I want to get `imagem.Width`, `imagem.Height`, `frontal.Canvas.Left`, `frontal.Canvas.Top`, `frontal.Angle` and `line.Margin.Left`, so that I can programmatically generate an array of clickable shapes on the UserControl taking advantage of image simmetry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var controlTemplate= Application.Current.FindResource("FacePositionSource") as ControlTemplate;
var controlTemplateContent = controlTemplate.LoadContent();
var img = GetChildOfType<Image>(controlTemplateContent);
```

and code for receiving child element

```
 public static T GetChildOfType<T>(DependencyObject depObj)
where T : DependencyObject
    {
        if (depObj == null) return null;

        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);

            var result = (child as T) ?? GetChildOfType<T>(child);
            if (result != null) return result;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Worked fine! It's worth mentioning that, in my case, `controlTemplateContent` is a Grid, so another possible approach would be to cast it to Grid and access their elements via `Children` property, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The best form of do this when the `element` which want find have an `name` is:

In the `CodeBehind`, for example find the `Image` control:

```
    // mycontrol is the control which use the ControlTemplate
    mycontrol.ApplyTemplate();

    // here you have your image
    var innerImage= mycontrol.Template.Findname("imagem", mycontrol) as Image;
```

Comment: Actually not, because the code behind runs in other UserControl, from which I want to read the content of the ControlTemplate (which by the way is for another type). Read the "context" part on my question.